# How to delete row from b-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi i just want to ask how to delete item/row in b-table. I tried to send item by `@click.prevent="deleteCustomItem(data.data.item)`
but i can't use delete because I am in strict mode.

My table:

```
 <custom-item-grid ref="customItemGrid" :is-busy="gridIsBusy" :key="invoice.id" :fields="gridItemsFields" :items="gridCustomItems">

    <template slot="action-buttons" slot-scope="data">
        <b-button v-b-tooltip.hover title="{{ __('Odstranit vlastní položku') }}" variant="danger" @click.prevent="deleteCustomItem(data.data.item)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></b-button>
    </template>

</custom-item-grid>
```

deleteCustomItem

```
 deleteCustomItem(item) {
     console.log(item);
     this.showConfirmDialog('Delete', 'Are you sure?').then(value => {
         if (value === true) {

             //CODE HERE
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Did you tried with [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)?

Comment: I am not sure how to reffer to the table in my remove method like this, becouse table is in separate component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stored this **b-table** items(like rows) in some array of Vue instance and then you rendered  those items using `v-for` then you can try to find this item using `.find()` in your array and delete it using `.splice()`. If it will not work you can get parent of your node and try to use `.removeChild`

Comment: I think it will be better to get parent of my node but i'm not sure how to refer to him.

Comment: You can use props. to send this array to your child table component and then using for example EventBus ```emit``` your custom event (for example deleteRow) in children component and add index of rowToDelete then in you parent component you can intercept this event in your parentComponent using ```.on()``` and delete item of array (index of this item will be available in payload). If you want to read more about eventBus you can do it here : [EventBus](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
this.$delete(this.$refs.customItemGrid.items,item);
```